# Highlighting a particular control while capturing screenshot of a dialog in web page in c#

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I have a requirement to capture the screen shot of the opened dialog with a particular html control highlighted ( whose static id is given ). currently I Implemented the code following manner :

```
public void Snapshot()
{
    Image currentImage = null;
    currentImage = GetOpenedDialogFrame().CaptureImage();
}

public UITestControl GetOpenedDialogFrame()
{
    var dialogsFrames = new HtmlDiv(this.BrowserMainWindow.UiMobiControlDocument);
    dialogsFrames.SearchProperties.Add(new PropertyExpression(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.Class, "mcw-dialog", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains));
    var dialogs = dialogsFrames.FindMatchingControls();
    if (dialogs.Count == 0)
    {
       return null;
    }

    return dialogs[dialogs.Count - 1];
}
```

Now I have to write the code to highlight the particular html control while taking a screenshot. The `DrawHighlight()` method of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll` does not take any parameter so how can I highlight a particular html control in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

`DrawHighlight()` is a method of a UI Control. It could be used in this style:

```
public void Snapshot()
{
    Image currentImage = null;
    var control = GetOpenedDialogFrame();
    // TODO: protect the code below against control==null.
    control.DrawHighlight();
    currentImage = control.CaptureImage();
}
```

Whilst that answers your question about `DrawHighlight`, I am not sure it will achieve what you want. Please see [this question the Microsoft forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/46f02980-2c89-4773-84a3-f00d0ac745af/visual-studio-2013-update-4-captureimage-with-drawhighlight-missing-blue-rectangle-in?forum=vstest) where they are trying to do a similar screen capture.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply user the playback settings:

```
Playback.PlaybackSettings.LoggerOverrideState = HtmlLoggerState.AllActionSnapshot;
```

This will produce the html log file with all the screenshots that your codedui test went threw.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for the matching controls you can try to highlight each one of them. 
something like:

```
      foreach( var control in controls)      
      {
       control.drawhighlight();
      }
```

that way you'll be able to which controls are located by the playback(qtagent to be more precise). furthermore this will help you decide  which instance to refer to. (run and wait to see which controls are highlighted, pick the one you need and hard code it to be part of the test).

so after the test run you'll end up with something like:

```
     var dialogs = dialogsFrames.FindMatchingControls();
     dialogs[desiredLocation].drawhighlight();
```

hope this helps.